# reStructuredText inline code followed by 's' results in `Inline interpreted text or phrase reference start-string without end-string.`?

Tags: restructuredtext

In reStructuredText, `` :code:`Observation` `` will create an inline code block which appears in the document as `Observation`. In my case, it's referring to my `Observation` class. In the resulting document I want to be able to do things like use the possessive form (`Observation`'s) and refer to multiple of the object (`Observation`s). However, the latter results in an warning/error. That is, `` :code:`Observation`s `` results in

```
sphinx.errors.SphinxWarning: Inline interpreted text or phrase reference start-string without end-string.
```

Notably, in other cases where I use non-alpha symbols after the inline code (`` :code:`Observation`'s ``, `` :code:`Observation`. ``, etc), the document compiles as expected.

Why is a character like `s` not allowed immediately after the inline code interpreted text? How can I achieve a similar goal, in particularly, making sure the raw reStructuredText document is still clean written/readable, yet also compiles the correct way?

Comment: Instead of `:code:`, why not use [inline literals](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#inline-literals)?

Comment: @StevePiercy, an inline literal seems to have the same problem (e.g., `\`\`Observation\`\`s`, results in the same warning/error). Additionally, although the inline literal and interpreted text code role might appear the same in many contexts, they also may be processed differently.

Answer (score 9):

By default, reStructuredText only allows certain punctuation and whitespace after an inline markup according to the [inline markup recognition rules](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#inline-markup-recognition-rules). Specifically, by default, an inline markup can only be immediately followed by

> - whitespace
> - one of the ASCII characters - . , : ; ! ? \ / ' " ) ] } >
> - a similar non-ASCII punctuation character

The reStructuredText parser setting [`character_level_inline_markup`](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/user/config.html#character-level-inline-markup) can be set to `True` to relax these requirements. It should be noted, though, this has the potential to change the expected behavior of other parts of the inline markup (see the warning at the [`character_level_inline_markup`](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/user/config.html#character-level-inline-markup) link).

Another alternative is to simply put an escaping backslash before the character that comes immediately after the inline markup (e.g., `` :code:`Observation`\s ``), but this usage is [explicitly discouraged](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#character-level-inline-markup-1) and recommended to be used only when there is no other alternative because of how it effects the readability of the original document.